# Drag and Drop item in tree to other panel in GWT

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I am implementing to make a new dashboard. I must drag the widget(tree item) from tree and drop to panel. I am using the **gwt-dnd** frame work. I have issue when I drag item from tree, the item will be moved out of tree. Please tell me how i can keep the item in tree when I drag this item from tree.
Please tell me your suggestion. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Although gwt-dnd is a good library, I'd rather use [gwtquery-dnd](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers) because of its simplicity and features. I think [this example](http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/branches/droppable_1_0/demo/PermissionManagerSample/PermissionManagerSample.html) in the examples collection of gquery-dnd makes almost what you query.

[EDITED]

If you dont want the dragged element be removed from the original tree as you suggest in your comment, dont remove it from the dataprovider list, in this example modify the line #345 of the `MemberDatabase.java`

```
if (member.getPermission() != Permission.NON_MEMBER) {
  previousList.getList().remove(member);
}
```

Comment: Hi Manolo, thank for your answer. but in your example when I drag the item from tree, this item will move out of tree.I want keep the item in tree when I drag it to other panel to create new some widget and drop to panel.

Comment: Thats not a matter of the DnD but the dataprovider of the table, edited my response so as you can modify the example to match what you say

Comment: I try to investigated gwtquery-dnd and I see it is very great. I can handle my problem now.Thank you so much.